# Why the git hook update doesn't work when run git push

Tags: git

As it said that the hook update is invoked by **git-receive-pack** on the remote repository, which happens when a **git-push** is done on a local repository. Now I add `echo 'update run'` in update, but when I run **git-push**, the hook update just doesn't run, cause I did not see the info `'update run'`, why it comes to be that result? thks!

Comment: Which `update` did you update?

Comment: have you set the `+x` (executable) bit of the hook file, as described in `man githooks` ?

Comment: You might want to try `echo 'update run' > /some/writable/file` to see if it’s not just the output that doesn’t get displayed.

Comment: How to set the +x(executable)bit of the hook file ??? I suppose that this might be caused by 'git-receive-pack'on the other end. But I do not know how to deal with it, please provide me the detail step to get this problem done? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question. 
The update script on your working direction would not run, the script only run on the server-side.